SSRS report expression issue
I have text as follow (some question don't have number which I'll ignore):

Question 1
Question 2

and I'm trying to extract the question numbers to sort them A-Z, if there is a question number or assign 0 if there is no number.
For that I came up with this expression:
=IIf(IsNothing(InStr(Fields!questiontext.Value,".")), 0, CInt(Left(Fields!questiontext.Value,InStr(Fields!questiontext.Value,"."))))
Now, when I run my report I get following:
Converting from string "" to type integer is not valid.
I was expecting that the expression return 0 for the questions without number and return the number of the question if there is any.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

I think IsNothing() is only for null checks. Try = 0 instead. Also, subtract 1 from the second InStr().

InStr() will return 0 if it doesn't find the search string, I believe

I've tried with = 0 and I'm getting same error. I also tried Fields!questiontext.Value.ToString.Contains(".") but no luck.

Haven’t had to work with SSRS in a long time, but testing this out I recalled one annoying bit about it: iif() always evaluate both sides. So regardless of your check, if CInt() can’t convert the substring to int you’ll get an #Error.
Try using Val(). It defaults to 0 if it can’t convert, so you don’t even need the iif with all the duplication:
=Val(Left(Fields!questiontext.Value, InStr(Fields!questiontext.Value, ".")))

Technically this includes the period in the substring, but Val() can handle it and decrementing the length parameter will result in #Error in cases where it goes negative.
The results will look like this:


Thanks BenderBoy your solution fixed my issue.
